# Unable to get textfield input [JavaFX]

Tags: javafx

I am unable to extract user input from textfield in javafx.

When I click the button, I want the text from the textfield should be printed in console but it displays nothing. Here is a screenshot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRei8.png)

Controller Class:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        textField = new TextField();
        System.out.println("You clicked me!" + textField.getText());
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="javafxapplication4.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" 
onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" 
minWidth="69" />
      <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="86.0" layoutY="137.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

What is the mistake, and can you provide an explanation if possible?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `textField = new TextField();` you are redefining the textField instance that's why you're getting empty value, but you're already instanciating the `TextField` with the `@FXML` annotation so to retrieve the text inside that textField (already defined before) change your method to this :

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!" + textField.getText());
    label.setText("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Earlier I was getting a null pointer exception and for solving it I added this line. Later I found out that I had to use "fx:id" instead of "id" in FXML file and kept that line as it is. I was dumb :p